# Submit a form from ajax returned html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm attempting to submit a form that's embedded in the HTML response of an AJAX request, but can't seem to get the form to actually submit.

I have something like:

```
    // get the cart page
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "cart.asp"

    }).success(function(cartHTML) {

        // build dom tree, and make it parsable
        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var doc = parser.parseFromString(cartHTML, "text/html");

        // set sku qty to zero and resubmit form which recalculates totals
        doc.getElementById('someProduct').value = 0;

        // this does not work, yet returns no error
        // the form does indeed exist in `doc`
        doc.forms['recalculate'].submit();

        // now get the checkout page again
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "checkout.asp"

        }).success(function(checkoutHTML) {

            // fetches and replaces totals with updated values, etc.
            updateCheckoutPageTotals(checkoutHTML); // this works, used in other places
        });
    });
```

The above script runs without error, but the returned values from the second ajax request do not change from before. The expected result is to remove a particular product from the cart, and therefore return updated totals, without this product.

I've verified the returned `cartHTML` variable does indeed contain the cart's HTML page, and `doc.getElementById('someProduct').value = 0;` does set the form value to zero for that input element.

I've also replicated the above script in Chrome Dev Tools, assigning the ajax response data to a global variable and parsing it into a document tree, and attempted to submit the form this way without success either. Simply executing `doc.forms['recalculate'];` on the console does return the correct form, with the value of `someProduct` set correctly to zero.

Performing the above action without ajax directly on the `cart.asp` page and then submitting the form via javascript does indeed work - and I thought I could emulate that via ajax from the checkout page to make things easier for the customer, but submitting the form as I've done above, has no effect it seems.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the DOMParser you get a whole new document that only exists in memory, and you can't really trigger events or do much else with it.

A form that is to be submitted, must be added to the DOM, i.e. the current document, so the browser can redirect and send the data on submit

Seems like you don't won't to reload the page, but use ajax for the form instead

```
// get the cart page
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "cart.asp"
}).done(function(cartHTML) {
  var html = $(cartHTML);

  // set sku qty to zero and resubmit form which recalculates totals
  html.find('#someProduct').val("0");

  var form = html.find('name="recalculate"]');

  jQuery.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url  : form.attr('action'),
    type : form.attr('method'),
    data : form.serialize()
  }).done(function() {
        // form submitted  
    jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
      url: "checkout.asp"
    }).done(function(checkoutHTML) {
        updateCheckoutPageTotals(checkoutHTML);
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: I cannot submit the form natively, it has to be done through ajax. Redirecting the page won't work here. Attempting to conveniently allow a customer to remove a special product from their cart while on the checkout page, without refreshing/redirecting them.

Comment: Well, then there's no need to call `submit` is there, as that only submits the form ?

Comment: Seems like my best course then is to figure out how to construct the post and then submit it with ajax directly to the form's action attribute. Was hoping for an easier way... it's not a platform I have access to tinker with server-side things.

Comment: Probably something more like -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/xckqz346/1/

Comment: you're fiddle was what I needed. Please update your answer so I can accept.